# Google Apps Script - how to hide run message

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a question about running apps script on a Google Sheet.

I have a few scripts written that can apply a filter and remove a filter.

When I run the script from the button on the spreadsheet the script running/progress messages are displayed in a balloon. What can I do to hide these messages from the user?

Here is the script but all functions give the same results:

```
function PostRedFilterOnText() { 
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
   var FILTERCELL = 'A5'; 
//    spreadsheet.getRange(FILTERCELL).setValue('Filter On');    
   spreadsheet.getRange(FILTERCELL).setValue('Filter On') 
      .setFontColor('#ff0000') .setHorizontalAlignment("center")  
      .setVerticalAlignment("middle"); 
      BackgroundLightOrange(FILTERCELL); }
```

Comment: Can you share these scripts? Or the script that produces the balloons to appear?

Comment: Here is the script but all functions give the same results

function PostRedFilterOnText() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var FILTERCELL = 'A5';
  // spreadsheet.getRange(FILTERCELL).setValue('Filter On');
  spreadsheet.getRange(FILTERCELL).setValue('Filter On')
  .setFontColor('#ff0000')
  .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
  .setVerticalAlignment("middle");
  BackgroundLightOrange(FILTERCELL);
}

How can I attach a screen dump on this group ?
Regards